# Is the thread function in a threaded IRQ runs in atomic context?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I have registered a threaded interrupt handler as below:

```
ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(dev,
                    data->irq,
                    &abc_handle_irq,
                    &abc_thread_irq,
                    IRQF_SHARED,
                    DEVICE_NAME,
                    (void *)pdev);
```

abc_thread_irq() is the thread function which acts as a bottom half in this mechanism. This thread shares a resource with process context hence needs a lock. Now question 1. can this lock be a mutex_lock() (struct mutex lock) or it must use spin_lock_bh(). I am looking into a code which uses mutex_lock which to my mind is not ok as it can put the BH into sleep and if the BH thread is running in an atomic context then that in turn cause kernel panic. The threaded interrupt mechanism is new to me, so need help.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. No. 2. What was the second question?

Comment: @0andriy thanks so you mean it must be spin_lock_bh()? Is that correct? The second question is "does the thread function run in atomic context?"

Comment: Whatever suits better in your case. It maybe _bh variant, or maybe _irqsave one, or just plain one, who knows?

Comment: *In a threaded irq handler, such things as sleeping calls (wait queues, mutex, etc) can be used but are still not recommended.* I stand corrected, here effectively the answer to 1 - it's non-atomic context.

Comment: @0andriy thanks for the reply, would you please like to post your answer in the answer box, I can accept it then. Thanks.